# How can we apply Young's inequality here?

Tags: analysis, young-inequality

Let $a \geq 2 $.

How can we get, using Young's inequality, that $$ a^2 b^{2a-4} \leq \frac{1}{2} b^{2a-2}+ C a^{2a}$$

for some large enough C.

It seems like we are trying to apply it with $p=2$ and $q=2$ so we get

$$a^2 b^{2a-4} \leq  \frac{1}{2} {(b^{2a-4})}^2+ \frac{1}{2} {(a^2)}^2 \leq  \frac{1}{2} {(b^{2a-4})}^2+ C a^{2a}$$

since $a \geq 2$.

But I don't see how we get the first term to have the power $(2a-2)$?

Comment: @whoisit this is the case for $p=q=2$

Comment: There's a difference between $(a^n)^k$ and $a^{n^k}$

Comment: @Hamdiken I edited but the question still stands

Comment: Nope, you just edited $a$, not $b$.

Comment: @Hamdiken ok I think it's correct now thanks. But still a question